# Proof of divisibility of 6

Tags: number-theory

How to prove that if a number is divisible by 2 and 3 both,it is also divisible by 6.It should be proven by using Euclid's Division Lemma.

Comment: @Dietrich, Not really a duplicate of that question because the OP says the answer must use Euclid's Division Lemma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* Write $n=6q+r$ with $0 \le r \le 5$. Since $n$ is divisible by $2$, so is $r$. Since $n$ is divisible by $3$, so is $r$. What $r$ are possible?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Assume $2|m$, then $m=2k;$

Assume $3|m$ then $3|2k$.

Now use Euclid's lemma.